# Call Client Side function from Server side where i want to ASP.NET ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have Client-Side button event. After click call  sgnPdf(ID) if I can sign PDF.

[MyForm.aspx]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <% if (ViewData.CanSignPdf){ %>
    $(function() {
        $("#<%=btnSend.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            if ($('.IgnoreCheckBox').is(':checked')) {
                sgnPdf(<%=ViewData.NoticeID %>);
                return false;
            };
        });
    });
    <% } %>
</script>
```

But I need call this function from Server side after button click.

[MyForm.aspx.cs]

```
  protected void BtnSendClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormUnbindData();
        SaveMYData();
        //Here i want call client function sgnPdf(ID). How can I do this?
        ShowMyMessage();
    }
```

OK, you need to do just simply. For example call alert("message") in there.

---

Ok, its works!!! but i need call client-side method(javascript) from server-side(C#) synchronously, becouse client-side method not starting until server-side method ends (for example button_click event).

---

I try this:

```
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "anyId", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This is my alert message');</script>", true);
```

and no action, nothing.

Comment: +1 for the nice question by a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this when button click:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page),sgnPdf(ID), true); 

OR
    <asp:Button OnClientClick = "sgnPdf(ID)"/>
```

Use this on page load:

```
RegisterStartupScript("Unique key", "sgnPdf(ID);");
```

Here is a [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)

Comment: I think RegisterStartupScript works only in Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) event.

Comment: But i need call sgnPdf(ID) when after button click FormUnbindData() and SaveMYData(). THEN call sgnPdf(ID).

Comment: @Emis-- you can use RegisterClientScriptBlock for your need.

Answer (score 1):

try following....

```
protected void BtnSendClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         FormUnbindData();
         SaveMYData();
         **Edit**
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "anyId", "<script language='javascript'>sgnPdf('"+ID+"');</script>", true);            

         ShowMyMessage();
     }
```

Comment: if you were not able to call the javascript function from first method,i have changed it now,just an overload,try to use it and check whether it solves you problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UpdatePanel on your page then you can call client side function from server side using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Use below code in button click event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script234", "sgnPdf('"+ID+"');", true);
```

If you are not using UpdatePanel on your page then you can call client side function from server side using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

use below code in button click event

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script234", "sgnPdf('"+ID+"');", true);
```