# webbrowser doesn't invoke click on span

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to scrap some pages with c# using a webbrowser control.

In order to have all the information to scrap I have to click a span element which has an onclick event.

This is what the span looks like:

```
<span title="title" class="class" onclick="somefunction(value);"></span>
```

This is my code:

```
foreach (HtmlElement span in table.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
        {
            span.InvokeMember("click");
        }
```

Its really simple and for some reason it doesn't do anything. I have tried to evaluate the code and the result I was getting was null.

Any idea how to invoke that click?

Comment: what should the onclick event return?

Comment: the onclick event is supposed to run an AJAX request to the server and append it to the proper html tags in the DOM

Comment: so, evaluating the code would evaluate to null?

Comment: As i said in the post yes.
If i do: `var x = span.InvokeMember("click");` i get null

Comment: yeah, sorry, I misread the question

Comment: I don't think you can call client side code from the server side, the best you could do is register a scriptblock that will do it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583991/call-client-side-function-from-server-side-where-i-want-to-asp-net-ajax

Comment: @Pete I am not able to make any changes to the client side, do you think there is an other option to invoke the javascript code?

Comment: Maybe try to look at what somefunction method does and try to mimic that by requesting the url in the same way. That would give you the partial html and you can scrap on that.

Comment: @Otake I'v already looked in to that, the function is executing an AJAX request with a POST method, I am not aware of how to mimic a post request  with POST data using a webbrowser control.

Comment: @DrDark, do you have to use webbrowser-control? If it is for scrapping, there other framework classes you can use. Take a look at this link: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/

Comment: @Otake After hours of trying to make it work with _restsharp_ I understood that the site im trying to scrap allows browsers only to navigate through their site. I'm back to square 1 where I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example with .NET 4.5 and WPF but anything could be easily adjusted to fit the WinForm WebBrowser control.
I assume that your HTML page looks something like this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function somefunction(value){
          alert("clicked on: " + value);
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <span title="title" class="class" onclick="somefunction('span_01');">Blah blah blah</span>
      <span title="title" class="class" onclick="somefunction('span_02');">Blah blah blah</span>
      <span title="title" class="class" onclick="somefunction('span_03');">Blah blah blah</span>
    </body>
  </html>
```

and that you have a UserControl wrapping the WebBrowser control (XAML below)

```
  <UserControl x:Class="WebBrowserExample.WebBrowserAdapter"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
               xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
               mc:Ignorable="d" 
               d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
      <Grid>
          <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowserControl"></WebBrowser>
      </Grid>
  </UserControl>
```

Then a possible solution is to inject into the page a Javascript function that does what you want and call it from .NET.
Add the following methods to the WebBrowserAdapter class:

```
  void WebBrowserAdapter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      WebBrowserControl.LoadCompleted += WebBrowserControl_LoadCompleted;
      WebBrowserControl.Navigate("http://localhost:9080/console/span.html");
  }

  void WebBrowserControl_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      IncjectClickOnSpanElementScript();
  }

  private void IncjectClickOnSpanElementScript()
  {
      String script =
  @"      function triggerClicksOnSpan(){
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
    spans[i].click();
  }
  }";

      InjectScript(script);
      WebBrowserControl.InvokeScript("triggerClicksOnSpan");
  }

public void InjectScript(String scriptText)
{
    HTMLDocument htmlDocument = (HTMLDocument)WebBrowserControl.Document;

    var headElements = htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (headElements.length == 0)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("No element with tag 'head' has been found in the document");
    }
    var headElement = headElements.item(0);

    IHTMLScriptElement script = (IHTMLScriptElement)htmlDocument.createElement("script");
    script.text = scriptText;
    headElement.AppendChild(script);
}
```

You will need to add **Microsoft.mshtml** among the references of the project.
Please note that, in this simplified example, **the script is injected every time a page gets loaded**. I imagine that you will need to tweak the code to adapt to your needs

Comment: This looks like an awesome solution, what I didn't get is how do you inject the script. Is there a method called _InjectScript_ i don't know of?

Comment: sorry, i missed that one... i'm gonna edit the answer in a minute. [done]

Comment: Well after hours of hacking with it i still get nothing.

I did succeed injecting the script to the head tag of the html but  `webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("triggerSpans");` does absolutely nothing :( 

I tried 2 types of scripts 1 is using jquery and the other is native javascript, I did try them both in the browsers console and they did work. Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: One idea: test the scripts in InternetExplorer after setting it to IE 7 mode. Look at the console for every possible error. The default engine of the WebBrowser control is IE7 and some javascript functions are not compatible with it. If this is your case, you can change the engine by adding a key in the registry (I can tell you which key then)

Comment: The Jquery one is working properly in IE7 but the native one doesn't, it has errors. The question is does webbrowser has anyproblem running jquery.. and just in case i'd love to get that registry you talked about :) thank you very much~!

Comment: Take a look at this articles to learn how to change the IE engine used by the WebBrowser control: [link1](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version), [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx), [link3](https://codevomit.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/wpf-webbrowser-control-part-1)

Comment: Hi DrDark. Does this solve your problem then? If so, can you mark the answer as accepted, please? If not, can I help you further?